# Does a Warlock's Repelling Blast Stack with Lance of Lethargy?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, stacking, eldritch-invocations

Lance of Lethargy states:

> Lance of Lethargy Prerequisite: eldritch blast cantrip
>
> Once on each of your turns when you hit a creature with your eldritch
> blast, you can reduce that creature’s speed by 10 feet until the end
> of your next turn.

Repelling Blast states:

> Repelling Blast Prerequisite: eldritch blast cantrip
>
> When you hit a creature with eldritch blast, you can push the creature
> up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line.

If a warlock hits a creature with a single beam can that character stack both effects of being pushed back 10' and having their movement reduced by 10'?

Comment: Is there any reason why both effects can not occur simultaneously?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. There is no competing clause here, both invocations take effect.